# Multiple tags within a class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

How do I apply css styles to HTML tags within a class at once instead of repeating the class name each time.

```
.container h1,.container p,.container a,.container ol,.container ul,.container li,
.container fieldset,.container form,.container label,.container legend,
.container table {
  some css rules here
}
```

how do I reduce repetition of the class name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [LESS](http://lesscss.org/). It would come out looking like this.

```
.container {
    h1, p, a, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table {
        your styles here
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you're SOL. Sorry.

Comment: Cool! I didn't know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It will change everything you know about coding CSS. :)

Answer (score 3):

You cannot reduce the current selector of yours as far as pure CSS goes.

You might want to take a look at [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) or [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) for doing that.

Also, I just read your selector, seems like *you are covering almost every tag*, so if you are looking to target few properties to each tag, the best you can do with CSS is to use a `*` selector *(Universal selector)* which will match any type of element nested under an element having a `class` of `.container`

```
.container * {
   /* Styles goes here */
}
```

Apart from the above, some properties are inherited by few child elements from their parent such as `font-size`, `color`, `font-family` etc.

So you don't need to write those for each, because I saw you using `.container ul, .container li` which didn't make much sense to me.